# Wordpress CPT add new overwrites existing ones

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I'm working on a Wordpress projekt and added some custom post types and metaboxes. Inside my VM it all works fine, but on the server, the second CPT I add overwrites the previous one. This only happens for the CPT shops, the other ones I've added work like they should.

I've placed the code for CPT and the metaboxes in different files and included them inside my functions.php for each CPT.

Here's the file **custom-post-type-shop.php** for the shop

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: BUYeinander Shops
 * Version: 0.1
 * Text Domain: buy_shops
 **/

// Register Shop Custom Post Type
function buy_shops()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Shops', 'Post Type General Name', 'buy_shops'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Shop', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'buy_shops'),
        'menu_name' => __('Shops', 'buy_shops'),
        'name_admin_bar' => __('Shops', 'buy_shops'),
        'archives' => __('Shop Archives', 'buy_shops'),
        'attributes' => __('Shop Attributes', 'buy_shops'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Shop:', 'buy_shops'),
        'all_items' => __('All Shops', 'buy_shops'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'buy_shops'),
        'new_item' => __('New Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'view_item' => __('View Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'view_items' => __('View Shops', 'buy_shops'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'not_found' => __('Not found', 'buy_shops'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not found in Trash', 'buy_shops'),
        'featured_image' => __('Shop Image', 'buy_shops'),
        'set_featured_image' => __('Set Shop image', 'buy_shops'),
        'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove Shop image', 'buy_shops'),
        'use_featured_image' => __('Use as Shop image', 'buy_shops'),
        'insert_into_item' => __('Insert into Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this Shop', 'buy_shops'),
        'items_list' => __('Shops list', 'buy_shops'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Shops list navigation', 'buy_shops'),
        'filter_items_list' => __('Filter Shops list', 'buy_shops'),
    );

    $args = array(
    'label' => __('Shops', 'buy_shops'),
    'description' => __('Shop-Eintrag', 'buy_shops'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => array(
            'title',
            // 'editor',
            // 'thumbnail',
            // 'comments',
            'revisions',
            // 'custom-fields'
        ),
        // 'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-store',
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
      );

    register_post_type('Shops', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'buy_shops', 0);
```

This is the file **meta-box-shop.php** for the metabox

```
<?php

// Metabox for shops
$prefix_shop = 'buy_shop_';

$regionargs = array(
    'post_type' => "regionen",
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$regionquery = new WP_Query($regionargs);
$regions = [];

if ($regionquery->have_posts()) {
    while ($regionquery->have_posts()) {
        $regionquery->the_post();
        $regionTitle = $regionquery->post->post_title;

        if (!in_array($regionTitle, $regions)) {
            $regions[] = $regionTitle;
        }
    }
}

$shop_meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'shop-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Shop Informationen',
    'page' => 'Shops',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Untertitel',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'description',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Straße',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'street',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Hausnummer',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'housenumber',
            'type' => 'number',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Postleitzahl',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'zipcode',
            'type' => 'number',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Stadt',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'city',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Internetadresse',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'url',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Region',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'region',
            'type' => 'select',
            'std' => '',
            'options' => $regions
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Zweigstelle',
            'desc' => '',
            'id' => $prefix_shop . 'branch',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'std' => ''
        ),
    )
);

add_action('admin_menu', 'shop_add_box');

// Add meta box
function shop_add_box()
{
    global $shop_meta_box;

    add_meta_box($shop_meta_box['id'], $shop_meta_box['title'], 'shop_show_box', $shop_meta_box['page'], $shop_meta_box['context'], $shop_meta_box['priority']);
}


// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function shop_show_box()
{
    global $shop_meta_box, $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="shop_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($shop_meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
        '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
        '<td>';

        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
            case 'number':
                echo '<input type="number" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:50%" />', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
            // case 'textarea':
            //     echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            //     break;
            case 'select':
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option ', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            break;
            // case 'radio':
            //     foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
            //         echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
            //     }
            break;
            case 'checkbox':
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
            break;
            }

        echo     '</td><td>',
        '</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'shop_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function shop_save_data($post_id)
{
    global $shop_meta_box;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['shop_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($shop_meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Add a meta box for image upload
 */


function lacuna2_case_study_bg( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'case_study_bg_submit', 'case_study_bg_nonce' );
    $lacuna2_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); ?>

    <p>
        <img style="max-width:200px;height:auto;" id="meta-image-preview" src="<?php if ( isset ( $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'] ) ){ echo $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'][0]; } ?>" /> <br>
        <input type="text" name="meta-image" id="meta-image" class="meta_image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'] ) ){ echo $lacuna2_stored_meta['meta-image'][0]; } ?>" />
        <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="Choose or Upload an Image" />
    </p>
<script>
jQuery('#meta-image-button').click(function() {

    var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {

        jQuery('#meta-image').val(attachment.url);
    jQuery('#meta-image-preview').attr('src',attachment.url);
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
    }

    wp.media.editor.open();

    return false;
});
</script>
<?php    

}

/**
 * Add Case Study background image metabox to the back end of Case Study posts
 */

function lacuna2_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'case-study-bg', 'Shop Bilddatei', 'lacuna2_case_study_bg', 'shops', 'normal', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'lacuna2_add_meta_boxes' );

/**
 * Save background image metabox for Case Study posts
 */

function save_case_study_bg_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'case_study_bg_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'case_study_bg_nonce' ], 'case_study_bg_submit' ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce  ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-image', $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_case_study_bg_meta_box' );
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure both post_types use an unique post_type key. That is the first parameter for the `register_post_type` function. See docs: [https://developer.wordpress.org/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)

2) Also: make sure to use a post_type key with only lowercase characters. As I may quote the documentation:

> **$post_type** *(string) (Required)* Post type key. Must not exceed 20
>   characters and may only contain **lowercase** alphanumeric characters,
>   dashes, and underscores.

So change:

`register_post_type('Shops', $args);`

into:

`register_post_type('shops', $args);`

Comment: I changed the key to buyshops to be sure that it is unike and to only use lower case. But still I get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In `register_post_type()` function, you have to put a unique `post_type_key` for each **Custom Post Type**. You're providing the same `post_type_key` for both **Custom Post Type** that's why the second one is overriding the first one. As you're using

```
register_post_type('shops', $args);
```

for the first one, you should use something else as `post_type_key` at the first parameter for the second **Custom Post Type**. You have to use anything unique for this. For example,

```
register_post_type('my-shop', $args);
```

Visit the [official doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for details.